# Non fungible tokens in EOS?

Tags: tokens, nonfungible

Like ERC20 token, EOS token has been developed. But is there any non-fungible tokens on EOS like ERC721 on Ethereum?

I have gone through [this](https://github.com/unicoeos/eosio.nft) one but didn't get much clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Nat implied, there is much more flexibility in EOS and thus many ways to implement NFTs.  If you accept a fuzzy definition of NFT, many games (like those linked above) already have NFTs.

There are effort at standardization for at least three reasons:

1) use of common market places that exist outside the game or application

2) making it easier for developers to build cool stuff

3) creating guarantees of ownership that exist outside the control of the game itself

Some or all of these points are addressed by different projects:

- Simple Assets, from CryptoLions:  https://medium.com/@cryptolions/introducing-simple-assets-b4e17caafaa4
- dGoods from Mythical Games:  https://www.businesswire.com/news/home/20190123005272/en/Mythical-Games-EOS-Lynx-Scatter-Team-dGoods
- Unico is still working on their standard too: https://github.com/unicoeos
- Also, the Korean Game developer ITAM is making their ITAM store:  https://www.theeoswriter.io/the-feed/2019/3/7/brendan-blumer-gives-itam-games-seal-of-approval-with-retweet They may be publishing their own digital asset standard, and/or accommodating other standards too.

Personally, I'm happy to see many attempts. I think now is the time for experimentation. I also think the community still needs some philosophical debate about what constitutes a digital assets. Does it just need to look and feel like a thing inside of your application, or does ownership need to exist outside the control of author?

*Full disclosure:  I am affiliated with CryptoLions and working on Simple Assets.*

Answer (score 2):

Short answer, yes.  Developers have replicated the fundamental concepts of ERC721; however, there is not some arbitrary numbered schema that everyone is going by like EOS769 that outlines this, nor will there be any need for this due to the inherent differences in the protocols.

The approach to ERC721 is to me like the approach to RAM.  There are many roads to get to a desired end result and there are little best practices to go off of.

Best bet would be to contact a project through their telegram to understand how they achieved their desired functionality in their application.

Maybe [Crypto Wizards](https://wizards.one/): https://t.me/wizardsone_channel

or

[EOS Knights](https://eosknights.io/): https://t.me/joinchat/IAL3EwvtSVMml_qkYPXbrw

There is also a telegram for NFT discussions: https://t.me/eosionft